# Analisis de Complejidad del Insertion sort Combinado con Busqueda Binaria

Tags: complejidad

Considera una variacion en el insertion sort que realiza una busqueda binaria para buscar la posicion correcta para insertar el nuevo elemento
Al utilizar el algoritmo de insertion sort junto con el de binary search para buscar la posicion correcta del nuevo elemento ordenado

Se que el binary search busca en O(nLog(n)) y que insertion sort en O(n^2). 
Y debido a la implementacion de estos dos juntos, el peor y caso promedio, como se verian afectados?

Comment: ¿ Cual es la pregunta **concreta** ? Las preguntas del tipo `haced el ejercicio por mí` terminan cerradas.

Comment: Mi pregunta es, dicha complejidad como se veria afectada? He modificado la pregunta para ver si asi es mas entendible. Me hago la idea de que seria siempre O(n^2) porque creo que el numero de inserciones o cambios que siempre realiza. O esta se veria afectado?